# Optimize Postgres for searching substrings of unknown length

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have a `character varying` column called `message` in a table `messages` that stores user messages from an IRC channel. With a chat bot, I allow users to search how many times a certain term has been typed. This term can be anything: one character, one word or multiple words. The table has ~15 million rows and query times can be pretty long.

I use the following query to find all substrings matching `term` case-insensitive:

```sql
select sum(array_length(string_to_array(LOWER(message), LOWER('term')), 1) -1) from messages;
```

The query uses sequential scan. When I `set enable_seqscan = off;` it uses the `btree` index that I also have on the table. The table also has a trigram index, but it never gets used.

What angle would you be looking at to improve query performance?

I use Postgres 14.9

Comment: It's unlikely that a single character will ever use an index because a lot of characters will match most of your messages. And obviously that `string_to_array` stuff you are doing isn't going to match any indexes either.

Comment: pg_trgm supports a defined set of operations (as documented).  string_to_array is not one of them.  You can reason through that string_to_array can only return more than one element if LIKE matches with the same term (decorated fore and aft with %, and provided the term does not have % of _ of its own), but that is not a reasoning through which PostgreSQL does for you.  You will need to explicitly write it into your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use postgreSQL optimization for this application? Yes, but not the way you have organized it.

Start by counting `messages` rows where the `message` column contains an arbitrary user-furnished search term.  You can do so with this query.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE message ILIKE '%term%'
```

Then, create a so-called [trigram index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) on that column you want to search. You'd do that like so.

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY message_text ON messages
  USING GIN (message gin_trgm_ops);
```

This index setup, uniquely to postgreSQL, accelerates the `LIKE` and `ILIKE` predicates.

This technique returns the number of messages containing *one or more* occurences of the search term, whereas your requirement calls for returning the *total number* of occurences of the search term.  To get the total number you can use a subquery to filter in just the messages with any occurences of the term, then count those. That will be faster than searching all the messages.

```sql
select sum(array_length(string_to_array(LOWER(message), LOWER('term')), 1) -1)
  from (
     SELECT message FROM messages WHERE message ILIKE '%term%'
  ) subset
```

If this were my app, before putting it into production I would disallow searching on terms shorter than three or four letters, and I might even create a table of disallowed stop words. That's because these queries will slow down when they return large counts. Somebody could use a short search term like `'e'` to deny service to your users.

Comment: Thank you, this sub-select drastically improved my performance! As a follow-up, off-topic question: would you use postgreSQL for this kind of application or are there better suited solutions?

Comment: I really like postgreSQL's unique ability to optimize these wildcard LIKE filters with trigram indexes. Other DBMSs have their own flavors of text search. I would stick with postgreSQL for this for now. If your application turns out to be successful on a vast scale, you might add apache lucene or something like it for natural language search. But for now you're good, I think.